# Is it possible to specify condition in Count()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to specify a condition in `Count()`? I would like to count only the rows that have, for example, "Manager" in the Position column.

I want to do it in the count statement, not using `WHERE`; I'm asking about it because I need to count both Managers and Other in the same `SELECT` (something like `Count(Position = Manager), Count(Position = Other))` so `WHERE` is no use for me in this example.

Comment: Boo to all the * users, use Count(SomeColumnInYourTable) where Position = 'Manager'

Comment: @Mark: On all modern databases, this doesn't make **any** difference.

Comment: Please point us to some literature if you have some. Thanks Philippe

Comment: You could also give one single example where it does make a difference.

Comment: @Mark & Philippe: Actually it can make a greate difference. If the field is nullable and not indexed, the query need to touch every record in the table, so using count(*) and count(field) can give differnet results and different performance.

Comment: I'm under the impression that * is only excuseable in EXISTS queries, this is SQL Server that I'm talking about. There are lots of performance myths I accept, but I have worked on modern systems with large tables where it does make a difference.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to start a Sql internals war. @Phillipe sorry if I sounded big headed.

Comment: I've analyzed execution plans for count(*) vs count(x) for years, and so far I haven't found a single one that showed a difference in performance. That's why I would really like to see an example of a query where there is a difference.

Comment: @Matthew: we're not talking about `SELECT *`, but `SELECT COUNT(*)`, which is a totally different beast.

Answer (score 921, accepted):

If you can't just limit the query itself with a `where` clause, you can use the fact that the `count` aggregate only counts the non-null values:

```
select count(case Position when 'Manager' then 1 else null end)
from ...
```

You can also use the `sum` aggregate in a similar way:

```
select sum(case Position when 'Manager' then 1 else 0 end)
from ...
```

Comment: what if my field is integer and I want to match null. it doesn't work this way
select count(case IntegerField when 'NULL' then 1 else null end)
from

Comment: @Faizan `null` is special. Use `case when IntegerField is null then ...`

Comment: When working with boolean fields you can use this : `SUM(CONVERT(int, IsManager))`

Comment: SQL Server implies an `else null` for `case` statements, so the `count()` example can be 10 characters shorter (if you count the space).

Comment: For some curious reason the `sum` aggregate is somewhat slower than `case` in MSSQL. I did not observe any difference in PostgreSQL.

Comment: If you want to get a count of how many managers there are then add `distinct` before the word case

Answer (score 259):

Assuming you do not want to restrict the rows that are returned because you are aggregating other values as well, you can do it like this:

```
select count(case when Position = 'Manager' then 1 else null end) as ManagerCount
from ...
```

Let's say within the same column you had values of Manager, Supervisor, and Team Lead, you could get the counts of each like this:

```
select count(case when Position = 'Manager' then 1 else null end) as ManagerCount,
    count(case when Position = 'Supervisor' then 1 else null end) as SupervisorCount,
    count(case when Position = 'Team Lead' then 1 else null end) as TeamLeadCount,
from ...
```

Comment: @RedFilter It's not even necessary to specify the `else` part, just `end` it right after the `1`.

Comment: @Denis: correct - I often leave the `else` in as it better documents the results of the case statement, especially for novie SQL developers. For brevity, it can be removed in this case.

Comment: You can also chain conditions, i.e. `case when Position = 'Manager' OR Position = 'Team Lead' then 1 end`, nice!

Answer (score 59):

@Guffa 's answer is excellent, just point out that maybe is cleaner with an IF statement

```
select count(IIF(Position = 'Manager', 1, NULL)) as ManagerCount
from ...
```

Comment: I used this, however, it should be IIF, not IF. :) https://database.guide/sql-server-if-vs-iif-whats-the-difference/

Comment: @Brian MacKay, you are right, I was thinking on mysql ^^¡, answer edited.

Answer (score 45):

Depends what you mean, but the other interpretation of the meaning is where you want to count rows with a certain value, but don't want to restrict the `SELECT` to JUST those rows...

You'd do it using `SUM()` with a clause in, like this instead of using `COUNT()`:
e.g.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Position = 'Manager' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ManagerCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Position = 'CEO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CEOCount
FROM SomeTable
```

Answer (score 28):

If using Postgres or SQLite, you can use the Filter clause to improve readability:

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE POSITION = 'Manager') AS ManagerCount,
  COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE POSITION = 'Other') AS OtherCount
FROM ...
```

BigQuery also has `Countif` - see the support across different SQL dialects for these features here:
https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter

Answer (score 13):

You can also use the Pivot Keyword if you are using SQL 2005 or above

[more info](http://unboxedsolutions.com/sean/archive/2004/08/30/302.aspx) and from [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM @Users
PIVOT (
    COUNT(Position)
    FOR Position
    IN (Manager, CEO, Employee)
) as p
```

Test Data Set

```
DECLARE @Users TABLE (Position VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Users (Position) VALUES('Manager')
INSERT INTO @Users (Position) VALUES('Manager')
INSERT INTO @Users (Position) VALUES('Manager')
INSERT INTO @Users (Position) VALUES('CEO')
INSERT INTO @Users (Position) VALUES('Employee')
INSERT INTO @Users (Position) VALUES('Employee')
INSERT INTO @Users (Position) VALUES('Employee')
INSERT INTO @Users (Position) VALUES('Employee')
INSERT INTO @Users (Position) VALUES('Employee')
INSERT INTO @Users (Position) VALUES('Employee')
```

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean just this:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM YourTable WHERE Position = 'Manager'
```

If so, then yup that works!

Comment: The edit shows that he does not want to restrict the rows with a WHERE clause

Answer (score 5):

I know this is really old, but I like the `NULLIF` trick for such scenarios, and I found no downsides so far. Just see my copy&pasteable example, which is not very practical though, but demonstrates how to use it.

`NULLIF` might give you a small negative impact on performance, but I guess it should still be faster than subqueries.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE ( id [int] NOT NULL, field [varchar](50) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @tbl (id, field)
SELECT 1, 'Manager'
UNION SELECT 2, 'Manager'
UNION SELECT 3, 'Customer'
UNION SELECT 4, 'Boss'
UNION SELECT 5, 'Intern'
UNION SELECT 6, 'Customer'
UNION SELECT 7, 'Customer'
UNION SELECT 8, 'Wife'
UNION SELECT 9, 'Son'

SELECT * FROM @tbl

SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [total]
    ,COUNT(1) - COUNT(NULLIF([field], 'Manager')) AS [Managers]
    ,COUNT(NULLIF([field], 'Manager')) AS [NotManagers]
    ,(COUNT(1) - COUNT(NULLIF([field], 'Wife'))) + (COUNT(1) - COUNT(NULLIF([field], 'Son'))) AS [Family]
FROM @tbl
```

Comments appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did to get a data set that included both the total and the number that met the criteria, within each shipping container. That let me answer the question "How many shipping containers have more than X% items over size 51"

```
select
   Schedule,
   PackageNum,
   COUNT (UniqueID) as Total,
   SUM (
   case
      when
         Size > 51 
      then
         1 
      else
         0 
   end
) as NumOverSize 
from
   Inventory 
where
   customer like '%PEPSI%' 
group by
   Schedule, PackageNum
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, boolean expressions evaluate to 0 or 1, so the following aggregation works:

```sql
select sum(Position = 'Manager') as ManagerCount
from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Note with PrestoDB SQL (from Facebook), there is a shortcut:

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html

> count_if(x) → bigint
>
> Returns the number of TRUE input values. This
>   function is equivalent to count(CASE WHEN x THEN 1 END)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bla WHERE Position = 'Manager'
```

Comment: No, question explicitly says "I want to do it in the count statement, not using WHERE"

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use a simple WHERE clause to select only the count some record.

Comment: Why do I get a down vote? After I answered (or may be the same time), many people answered the similar thing and they do not get any downvote. /:(

Comment: You get a downvote because the question is "specify condition in Count" NOT "Count values by condition".

So you are answering the wrong question

Comment: Its a bit unfair to downvote the answer, when the answer was written it was a correct solution to the question.... he added the extra text 4 minutes after this answer!