# postgreSQL Query - Count column values matching on two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need help creating an SQL query to count rows broken out on two separate columns.

This is the DDL for my Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Agency (
  id SERIAL not null,
  city VARCHAR(200) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE Customer (
  id SERIAL not null,
  fullname VARCHAR(200) not null,
  status VARCHAR(15) not null CHECK(status IN ('new','regular','gold')),
  agencyID INTEGER not null REFERENCES Agency(id),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Sample of the AGENCY table:

| id | 'city' |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'London' |
| 2 | 'Moscow' |
| 3 | 'Beijing' |

Sample of the CUSTOMER table:

| id | 'fullname' | status | agencyid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Michael Smith' | 'new' | 1 |
| 2 | 'John Doe' | 'regular' | 1 |
| 3 | 'Vlad Atanasov' | 'new' | 2 |
| 4 | 'Vasili Karasev' | 'regular' | 2 |
| 5 | 'Elena Miskova' | 'gold' | 2 |
| 6 | 'Kim Yin Lu' | 'new' | 3 |
| 7 | 'Hu Jintao' | 'regular' | 3 |
| 8 | 'Wen Jiabao' | 'regular' | 3 |

I want to count the new customers, regular customers and gold_customers by city.

I need to count separately for ('new','regular','gold').  Here is the output I want:

| 'city' | new_customers | regular_customers | gold_customers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'Moscow' | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 'Beijing' | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 'London' | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL: is it possible to specify condition in Count()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400078/t-sql-is-it-possible-to-specify-condition-in-count)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was struggling with the same a couple of weeks ago.
This is what you need.

```
SELECT 
  Agency.city,
  count(case when Customer.status = 'new' then 1 else null end) as New_Customers,
  count(case when Customer.status = 'regular' then 1 else null end) as Regular_Customers,
  count(case when Customer.status = 'gold' then 1 else null end) as Gold_Customers 
FROM 
  Agency, Customer 
WHERE 
  Agency.id = Customer.agencyID 
GROUP BY
  Agency.city;
```

Answer (score 7):

You could group on `city`, and then sum the number of statuses in each city:

```
select  city
,       sum(case when c.status = 'new' then 1 end) as New
,       sum(case when c.status = 'regular' then 1 end) as Regular
,       sum(case when c.status = 'gold' then 1 end) as Gold
from    customer c
join    agency a
on      c.agencyid = a.id
group by
        a.city
```

Comment: Thanks Andomar, it works fine but doesn't give me the zeros in Gold. You guys are fast

Comment: A bit late to the game but maybe the difference in zeros is due to sum vs count (which gain a false equivalency due to out returning of 1 vs nothing)?