# SQL query select with ranges

Tags: sql, select

I have one table like this...

```
+---------+------------+------+-------+
|  City   | NamePeople | Age  | Money |
+---------+------------+------+-------+
| Paris   | John       |  10  |  200  |
| London  |  Marie     |  21  |  300  |
| Paris   |  Kevin     |  50  |  250  |
| Paris   |  Julia     |  45  |  150  |
+---------+------------+------+-------+
```

I need a result with ranges  , something like this

```
+---------------+------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
|      City     | Sum(Money) | CountPeopleWithAge<30 | CountPeopleWithAge>30   |
+---------------+------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
|   Paris       |       600  |                    1  |                      2  |
|   London      |       300  |                    1  |                      0  |
+---------------+------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
```

How do I do this with sql select?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the code you've tried and what went wrong. `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400078/is-it-possible-to-specify-condition-in-count

Comment: What about people whose age is exactly 30?

Comment: @Laurence I think there's some more issues with the expected output http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d964b/2

Comment: @ConradFrix fixed those too, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select
    City,
    Sum(Money),
    Sum(Case When Age < 30 Then 1 Else 0 End),
    Sum(Case When Age > 30 Then 1 Else 0 End)
From
    table
Group By
    City
```

Comment: Laurence' answer looks the best, but don't forget about the EXACTLY 30 years old people.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Query,

```
SELECT City, 
    SUM(Money), 
   SUM(case when Age < 30 then 1 else 0 end),
   SUM(case when Age > 30 then 1 else 0 end)
FROM tableA
GROUP BY City
```