# SQL Case and Cast in Count function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to count records from two fields only if they meet a specific criteria.

This [[Is it possible to specify condition in Count()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400078/is-it-possible-to-specify-condition-in-count) ] post was helpful, but it doesn't account for casting varchar to int.

 
Here is my code:

```
SELECT Mailing_Id ,Mailing_Nm,Subject_Line,Campaign_Nm,Start_Ts,End_Ts, Mailed_Cnt, Invalid_Cnt ,Actual_Sent_Cnt ,Bounce_Cnt ,Open_Cnt ,Click_Cnt
,count(case ag.logtype when '7' then 1 end) as Unsubs
,count(case ag.category when '1' then 1 end) as Block
,count(case ag.category when '2' then 1 end) as Hard
,count(case ag.category when '3' then 1 end) as Soft
,count(case ag.category when '4' then 1 end) as Tech
,count(case ag.category when '9' then 1 end) as Unknown
  FROM [StrongMailTracking].[dbo].[SM_MAILING_SUMMARY] ms left join sm_aggregate_log ag on ms.mailing_id = ag.mailingid
  WHERE datepart(year,start_ts) = 2015 and (mailing_nm not like '%delivery report%' and mailing_nm not like '%daily helpdesk%' and mailing_nm not like '%test%')
  GROUP BY Mailing_Id ,Mailing_Nm ,Subject_Line ,Campaign_Nm ,Start_Ts ,End_Ts ,Mailed_Cnt ,Invalid_Cnt ,Actual_Sent_Cnt ,Bounce_Cnt ,Open_Cnt ,Click_Cnt
ORDER BY mailing_id asc
```

Please draw your attention to the 6 case statements. Logtype is int, Category is varchar. 
I've tried:

- removing the single quotes
- adding ... case cast( - as int) when ...
- removing single quotes while casting
- casting as numeric first then int 
  But I keep getting this error: "Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
  Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'dynamic-preview-7179' to data type int."

   
  Does anyone have ideas on what to do?

Comment: I see no problem with that.  Unless the data type is an int an you comparing a string to an int

Comment: The problem is you can't use two data types in SQL case statements. It can only return one data type and there's a preference order in how it picks that. Use Gordon Linoffs answer. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Search for data types in that post if you want more info.

Comment: @Sam Gordon's answer didn't work, please see my comment to it

Comment: Do you have to remove all count statements for this query to work or did you try removing each count statement to see which causes the problem?

Comment: Also check the fields logtye and category in sm_aggregate_log table to see which contains 'dynamic-preview-7179'

Comment: @Sam each one causes the error message. Neither the category or logtype field contain 'dynamic-preview-7179', I even used a 'like' query. I feel like i've tried everything! D:

Comment: If logtype and category are supposed to have only integers can you add the below also in the where condition and see how it goes.

ISNUMERIC(ag.logtype) = 1 AND ISNUMERIC(ag.category) = 1

Comment: @Sam that did't work :< I appreciate your dedication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I commented before, ms.Mailing_Id is an int and ag.mailingid is a varchar. a colleague helped me out with this:

`FROM [StrongMailTracking].[dbo].[SM_MAILING_SUMMARY] ms left join sm_aggregate_log ag on CAST(ms.mailing_id As varchar(255)) = ag.mailingid`

Answer (score 1):

According to your description of the data types, this should work:

```
count(case ag.logtype when 7 then 1 end) as Unsubs,
count(case ag.category when '1' then 1 end) as Block,
count(case ag.category when '2' then 1 end) as Hard,
count(case ag.category when '3' then 1 end) as Soft,
count(case ag.category when '4' then 1 end) as Tech,
count(case ag.category when '9' then 1 end) as Unknown
```

Numbers should be compared to numeric constants; strings to string constants.

Although equivalent, I would write the logic as:

```
sum(case when ag.logtype = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as Unsubs,
```

Why?  Two reasons that are merely preferences:

- I prefer the more general `case` statement because I find that when modifying code, I often need to add in new conditions.  I prefer `IN` to using multiple `WHEN`s.
- I prefer `sum()` over `count()` because `count(2)` = `count(1)`.

Comment: I did try that, however I just copied and pasted your code to double check. I still received the same error: "Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'dynamic-preview-7179' to data type int."

Comment: @z0nia . . . In that case, the problem would not be the aggregations.  I think the obvious conversion possibility is the `join` condition:  ` ms.mailing_id = ag.mailingid`.

Comment: I should have added that when I remove the 6 count statements, the query works! (That being said, ms.mailing_id is int and ag.mailingid is varchar)

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: @z0nia . . . Nothing comes to mind.  If those types are as you say, I don't see how the `COUNT()` would generate an error.