# Querying total number of rows with a number present

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access to query a table named "AllData" which contains a column "gender".

The gender column has data that is a number type, the number in this column is either 1 (male), 2 (female), 3 (other), or null.

I want to count how many males there are. I tried using the answers to this previous question [Is it possible to specify a condition in Count()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400078/is-it-possible-to-specify-condition-in-count). This is my best attempt at using the information from the top answer:

```
SELECT

COUNT(CASE gender WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)

FROM AllData;
```

But when I run this query I get an error message "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT(CASE gender WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)'. I am very new to SQL and so I cannot figure out which part of that line might be leading to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work in any database:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM AllData
WHERE gender = 1;
```

If you want all genders:

```
SELECT gender, COUNT(*)
FROM AllData
GROUP BY gender;
```

MS Access does not support the `CASE` expression.

Comment: Those work perfectly! Thanks for the tip about MS Access' limitations.