# SQL Query Separated Counters

Tags: sql, pyspark

I am working in a PySpark Shell with Hive data. The goal here is to gather counters for multiple items. Below I have an example dataframe and data query. A resource I used: [Is it possible to specify condition in Count()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400078/is-it-possible-to-specify-condition-in-count) but it was for limited Counters.

`DriveHealth = sqlContext.sql("Select Health From testdrivestatus")`

```
Health   |
----------
Healthy  
Healthy
Error A
Error B
Error C
```

The goal here is to create counters that will count:

1. Number of Drives with Health as Healthy
2. Number of Drives with Health that is **not** healthy, so Error A, Error B, and Error C.
3. Number of Drives with separate health status so a counter for Healthy, Error A, Error B and Error C.

In this case we would have something like this...

```
Health Counter
--------------
Healthy: 2
Unhealthy: 3
Error A: 1
Error B: 1
Error C: 1
```

Something I have tried, which works for a small amount of cases but I have over 60 different health statuses, and I was wondering if there was a better way to do this:

```
DriveHealth = sqlContext.sql("Select 
Count( case Health when 'Healthy' then 1 else null end) as Healthy,
Count( case Health is not 'Healthy' then 1 else null end) as UnHealthy,
Count( case Health when 'Error A' then 1 else null end) as ErrorA,
... (skipping typing Through Error C)
From testdrivestatus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to do is `group by` your Health column.

```
select
    count(*) as total,
    Health
from
    testdrivestatus
group by 
    Health
```

Comment: Duh! Dull moment for me. Thank you. I will accept this as soon as I can.

Comment: How would I add the columns that arent healthy? Would I just have to make a seperate case where it isn't Healthy?

Comment: @TJ72 I don't know which DB engine you're using, but rule of thumb is that any non-aggregate values (ie selecting a column instead of counting/sum/average/etc) should be in your group. So for example, to add an "ErrorCode" column, you could do `SELECT count(*), Healthy, ErrorCode FROM testdrivestatus GROUP BY Health, ErrorCode`