# How to use an expression in select count(...)? (Doctrine)

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm

I have `User` and `UserGroup` entities. Each user has a group (`UserGroup`), and each user has a boss (`User`).

I would like to get a list of groups, and decide if the current user is the boss of someone in the group. I already implemented this in SQL, and now I tried to solve it using Doctrine. This is what I tried:

```
$qb = em()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select(array('gr.id AS group_id', 'gr.name AS group_name', 'COUNT(us.boss = :current_user_id)>0 AS is_boss'))
    ->from('\App\Entity\UserGroup', 'ug')
    ->leftJoin('\App\Entity\User', 'us', 'WITH', 'us.group = ug.id')

    ->setParameter('current_user_id', $_SESSION['uid'])

    ->groupby('gr.id')
;

$groups = $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
```

Unfortunately I get an uncaught `QueryException`, and I have no idea how to fix that. How is it possible to put an expression inside the `COUNT(...)` function?

Comment: What is the error message? And you should `groupBy` with all columns, not only id.

Comment: It works without the `COUNT(...)` part. The error message just contains the DQL query: `SELECT gr.id AS group_id, gr.name AS group_name, COUNT(us.boss = :current_user_id)>0 AS is_boss
FROM \App\Entity\UserGroup ug
LEFT JOIN \App\Entity\User us WITH us.group = ug.id
GROUP BY gr.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Mysql case function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp) to do this:

```
$queryBuilder->addSelect('case when COUNT(case when us.boss = :current_user_id then 1 else 0 end)>0 then 1 else 0 end AS is_boss');
```

Reference

- [Is it possible to specify condition in Count()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400078/is-it-possible-to-specify-condition-in-count)