# Spark dataset count rows matching condition with agg() method (in Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm using Apache Spark 2.3.1 in Java. I want to count the number of rows in a dataset matching a given condition, by using the `agg()` method of the `Dataset` class.

For example, I want to count the number of rows where `label` equals to `1.0` in the following dataset:

```
SparkSession spark = ...

List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
rows.add(RowFactory.create(0, 0.0));
rows.add(RowFactory.create(1, 1.0));
rows.add(RowFactory.create(2, 1.0));

Dataset<Row> ds =
    spark.sqlContext().createDataFrame(rows,
        new StructType(new StructField[] {
            new StructField("id", DataTypes.LongType, false, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("label", DataTypes.DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty())}));
```

My guess is to use the following code:

```
ds.agg(functions.count(ds.col("label").equalTo(1.0))).show();
```

However, a wrong result is displayed:

```
+--------------------+
|count((label = 1.0))|
+--------------------+
|                   3|
+--------------------+
```

The right result should be of course `2`.

Is the `agg()` method not supposed to work this way?

Comment: looks like your condition isn't working inside agg,  what if you try filtering before count?  `df.filter(df.col("label").equalTo(1.0)).count();`

Comment: In fact my question is why the condition isn't working inside agg...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chlebek's answer is correct.

Using Java syntax:

```
ds.agg(functions.count(functions.when(ds.col("label").equalTo(1.0), 0))).show();
```

Note that, when using `count`, the `value` argument of the `when` function doesn't matter (it's equivalent to SQL `count(*)`).

Another way to accomplish the same would be to output a `1` and `sum` all results:

```
ds.agg(functions.sum(functions.when(ds.col("label").equalTo(1.0), 1))).show();
```

In this case the `value` must be exactly `1`.

Answer (score 1):

count in `agg()` will only count not null values, so it's possible to do this:

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
 ds.agg(count(when('label.equalTo(1.0),1).otherwise(null))).show()
```

I've found this solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1400115/9687910

Answer (score 0):

The `agg` method isn't supposed to work like this. Indeed what you need here is firstly to **group** your data per **label** and then apply an aggregation such as **count**, **max** and many more.

```
df.filter("label".equalTo(1.0)).groupBy('label').agg(count("*").alias("cnt"))
```

It refers to the following [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html).