# Conceptually understanding count with groupby

Tags: sql, postgresql

Question:

> Write a query that counts the number of 300lb+ players for each of the following regions: West Coast (CA, OR, WA), Texas, and Other (everywhere else).
> Reference : https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-case/

The relevant part of the table looks like this

| name | weight | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Giga | 370 | WY |
| Chad | 350 | OR |

this is the correct solution:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN state IN ('CA', 'OR', 'WA') THEN 'West Coast'
            WHEN state = 'TX' THEN 'Texas'
            ELSE 'Other' END AS arbitrary_regional_designation,
        COUNT(*) AS players
  FROM benn.college_football_players
 WHERE weight >= 300
 GROUP BY 1
```

output:

```
| arbitrary_regional_designation | players  |
|:-------------------------------|:---------|
| Other                          | 1590   |
| West Coast                     | 186  |
| Texas                          | 208   |
```

this makes sense to me, I am wondering why the below code doesn't give the right answer

```
SELECT CASE WHEN state IN ('CA','OR', 'WA') THEN 'West Coast'
            WHEN state = 'TX' THEN 'Texas'
            ELSE 'Other' END AS region,
      count(weight>=300) --what's different here?
FROM benn.college_football_players
group by region
```

output for the above query:

```
| region | count |
|:---- |:------:| 
| Other  | 20513    |
| West Coast  | 2944    |
| Texas  | 2841    |
```

would appreciate your insight.

Comment: What is the output with `count(case when weight>=300 then 1 else null end)`? I would guess that `weight>=300` evaluates to `True` or `False`, neither of which is `null`.

Comment: Why have you tagged both SQL server and postgresql? They are completely different products

Answer (score 2):

In the "correct solution" that you mentioned, the `WHERE` clause will filter the actual rows (i.e., remove them) so when you count using the `WHERE` clause, you're counting the remaining rows.

If you don't like the `WHERE` clause you could do something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN state IN ('CA','OR', 'WA') THEN 'West Coast'
            WHEN state = 'TX' THEN 'Texas'
            ELSE 'Other' END AS region,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE weight >= 300) AS relevant_weight_count
FROM benn.college_football_players
GROUP BY region
```

This should have the added benefit of counting when a region has zero players using the weight threshold (where as the `WHERE` clause wouldn't show the row altogether).

Putting the condition inside of the `COUNT` directly (without `FITLER`) will count the rows regarding of weight. You can find more information about this specific topic in other questions (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400078/is-it-possible-to-specify-condition-in-count)).