# SQL aggregate row values with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

The SQL code below will give me following output

```
SELECT Year, geo_code, Age, COUNT(*) AS Population 
FROM table_1
WHERE geo_code = 'AB23' 
  AND Year = 2023
GROUP BY Year, geo_code, Age
```

| Year | geo_code | Age | Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | AB23 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023 | AB23 | 2 | 12 |
| 2023 | AB23 | 3 | 11 |
| 2023 | AB23 | 5 | 14 |
| 2023 | AB23 | 6 | 10 |
| 2023 | AB23 | 7 | 5 |

However, I want to aggregate population count to '5+' if age is >=5.

For example:

| Year | geo_code | Age | Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | AB23 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023 | AB23 | 2 | 12 |
| 2023 | AB23 | 3 | 11 |
| 2023 | AB23 | 5+ | 29 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to specify condition in Count()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400078/is-it-possible-to-specify-condition-in-count)

Comment: Never store age. All your data will become out-of-date soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the classification in advance in a subquery. Then grouping is easy. For example:

```
SELECT Year, geo_code, g as age, COUNT(*) AS Population 
FROM (
  select t.*, case when age >= 5 then '5+' else '' + age end as g
  from table_1 t
) x
WHERE geo_code = 'AB23' AND Year = 2023
GROUP BY Year, geo_code, g
```

Comment: '' + age might not work if age is int. perhaps CAST(age as varchar(10)) is better

Comment: @siggemannen It actually [works](https://dbfiddle.uk/r79GEs1S) with `'' + age`. However, I agree that `CAST()` is easier on the eyes.